# MQTT is is not Connecting to Google IOT core After Retry

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mqtt, iot, esp32, mongoose-os

I am using Mangoose os + Google IOT core to create my last year automation project. i have used [this](https://mongoose-os.com/docs/mongoose-os/cloud/google.md) tutorial to develop a basic structure to create my project. now problem is when i try to connect my esp32 through my Mobile Hotspot, it works perfectly even after powercut of esp32(means reconnects to mqtt successfully after Powercut) but when i try to connect it through my Home wifi(Static IP provided by my Local ISP),

[image: First time connection with HomeWifi {image Link}]

for the first time connecting to my Home WIFI it connects to MQTT successfully. but when i powercut the ESP32 and reconnect esp32, it connects to Home WIFI but,

[image: MQTT fails to reconnect...{image Link}]

it Shows "MQTT is Connecting in 2552ms", as Shown in Below Image.
it dosent connect to MQTT server.

Comment: Could it be that you are using low number pins ... https://www.esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=8728                                                    
ESP 32 when wifi is used, low numbers pins cannot be used

Comment: Thank you for replying sir, but i don't think issue is with pins, it works perfectly fine on my phone's wifi, and another wifi at my office.

Comment: Does your office wifi has dynamic IP? If so, and as you mentioned it works perfectly, then it might be related to your static IP at your home or your router configuration.

Comment: yes sir @Fcojavmelo , it was realted to the ISP's System of IP allocation, when i use dynamic ip it works fine and when i use static ip it dosen't. thank you for your view, now i just need a workaround to make system work in static ip.